# QuickCheck Tests for Custom Type

Tags: haskell, functor, quickcheck

With the following Algebraic Data Type:

`data Cons a = Cons a (Cons a) | Empty deriving (Show, Eq)`

I wrote an instance of `Arbitrary`:

My **understanding** is that it's necessary to create an instance of `Arbitrary` for QuickCheck to know how to find a `Cons Int` to plug in for its tests.

```
instance Arbitrary (Cons Int) where
    arbitrary = elements [Empty, Cons 10 (Cons 100 (Cons 55 Empty)), Cons 1 Empty]
```

and a function:

```
makeArbitraryCons :: Gen (Cons Int)
makeArbitraryCons = arbitrary
```

Then, I wrote a QuickCheck test:

```
prop_id_functor_law_int ::  Cons Int -> Bool
prop_id_functor_law_int x = fmap id x == id x
```

And it works:

```
ghci> quickCheck prop_id_functor_law_int
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test):
Cons 10 (Cons 100 (Cons 55 Empty))
```

However, when I try to run the following test, it fails:

```
second_functor_law_int :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Cons Int -> Bool
second_functor_law_int f g x = left == right
  where left = fmap (f . g) $ x
        right = (fmap f) . (fmap g) $ x
```

with this error:

```
ghci> quickCheck second_functor_law_int

<interactive>:418:1:
    No instance for (Show (Int -> Int))
      arising from a use of `quickCheck'
    In the expression: quickCheck second_functor_law_int
    In an equation for `it': it = quickCheck second_functor_law_int
```

My questions are:

1. is it necessary to define an `Arbritrary` instance for a new
   data type (such as my `Cons a`)?
2. must I create a function that
   creates a `Gen (Cons Int)` - `makeArbitraryCons`?
3. lastly, what's going on when I run my second test via `quickCheck
   second_functor_law_int`?

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2. You can either: define an `Arbitrary` instance or create a `Gen ...` function and use something like the `forAll` combinator.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074021/866915) for an example of using `forAll` with a `Gen ...` function.

3. The signature of `second_functor_law_int` is:

   second_functor_law :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> Cons Int -> Bool

so by running `quickCheck second_functor_law_int` you are asking QuickCheck to create a random  `Int -> Int` function. Quickcheck requires its randomly generated arguments to be Show-able, and so you are getting this error since functions (in general) do not have `Show` instances.

With what you have it is possible to call `quickCheck` with specific functions `f` and `g`, e.g.:

```
quickCheck $ second_functor_law_int_int (+1) (*2)
```

Then QuickCheck will only generate random `Cons Int` values.

Btw, a better way to define `arbitrary` for an ADT like `Cons` is to use `sized`. Some examples:

- [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959889/866915)
- [Generating Recursive Data Types](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual_body.html#16)

Comment: For your answer to directly provide `Int -> Int`'s ( `(+1)` and `(*2)`, is that a work-around or a recommended, idiomatic approach?

Comment: afaik, QuickCheck cannot create a random `Int -> Int` function, so you have to supply your own.